# JNDI Configuration in context.xml based on Maven profile

Tags: java, maven

#### Given

I'm new to doing "funky stuff" with maven and I've run into a quandary.  I have two separate servers I need to deploy to and each as a slightly different JDNI resource profile as defined in `context.xml`

My file structure is as such: (*although i can change this if there is a better way*)

```
src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml
src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.devel.xml
src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.prod.xml
```

Depending on the deployment target I would like to use the appropriate `context.TARGET.xml` file.

#### Question

I understand I would need to setup two different build profiles such as:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>devel</id>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

but from here I get confused as to what the best solution is.  I understand with the war plugin I can exclude `context.xml` but from that point onwards i'm confused what to do.

Is there just a way to have a variable inside of my `context.xml` that i can have maven "write" as opposed to having 2 different configuration files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some hints.

- you need only one `context.xml` .
- replace the server specific entries in `context.xml` with custom maven properties. For example: ${myServer} or ${dbUser}
- define these properties in your profiles like this

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <properties>
          <myServer>srv-prod.yourcompany.com</myServer>
          <dbUser>james</dbUser>
      </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>devel</id>
      <properties>
          <myServer>srv-devel.yourcompany.com</myServer>
          <dbUser>richard</dbUser>
      </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

- configure the [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) properly.

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                    <targetPath>/META-INF</targetPath>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
           </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

- activate the appropriate profile within the maven build. For example, call `mvn -Pprod clean package` on the command line. Or activate the needed profile in your IDE. For `devl` use `-Pdevl` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use maven resource filtering to explicitly include or exclude specific files from the process-resources phase of the Maven build life cycle.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/context.prod.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>devel</id>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/context.devl.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

Comment: are `context.prod.xml` and `contex.devl.xml` proper names? Regarding conventions, best practices ... Don't you need extra coding for using either `prod` or `devl` ?

Comment: @Ulrich sorry I am unaware of the bets practices for this.  If you wanted to change the names before packaging you can always leverage the maven assembly plugin.