# Configuring maven filter to applicationContext.xml

Tags: maven

I'm trying to configure maven filter to change some values inside applicationContext.xml, see my filter:

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

Inside "WEB-INF" i have applicationContext.xml, see a peace of code:

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/${project.build.finalName}" />
```

When i execute `mvn install` maven generate another folder WEB-INF inside */WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF* with a new applicationContext.xml file where ${project.build.fileName} was resolved, but applicationContext.xml inside */WEB-INF/* have ${project.build.finalName} without resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Files in src/main/webapp and below aren't normal resources, but web resources. They are filtered by the [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31047372/1988304).

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                    <targetPath>/WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
           </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
```